# Передать данные в PHP

Tags: передача-данных, передача-параметров

**Доброго времени суток.**

Есть проект в котором есть два тарифа "Модуль «LITE»" и "Модуль «PRO»"

Есть форма:

```
<form action="request_cours.php" method="POST">

<input type="text" class="popup_input" name="user_name" placeholder="Имя">
<input type="text" class="popup_input" name="user_phone" placeholder="Телефоне">
<input type="email" class="popup_input" name="user_mail" placeholder="Email">
<input type="hidden" name="user_cours_lite" value="Модуль Lite">
<div class="checkbox">
<input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox_1">

<label for="checkbox_1" class="checkbox__label">Я согласен на обработку персональных данных.</label>
</div>

<button class="popup_lite_btn" name="user_cours_lite">принять участие</button>
```

Я нашел и сделал передачу заполняемых данных(Имя, телефон и емаил) и отправку их на почту. Но не могу придумать и найти как передать идентификатор курса LITE или PRO.

**Как должно работать:**
1) Пользователь нажимает на "Принять участие"
2) Заполняет Имя, телефон, емаил
3) Нажимает на кнопку "Принять участие"
4) На почту падает информация: 
Имя + телефон + емаил + информация какой курс выбрал пользователь.

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ:
в форму лайт добавьте

```html
<input type='hidden' name='course_type' value='lite'>
```

в форму про добавьте

```html
<input type='hidden' name='course_type' value='pro'>
```

Comment: Что написать в файле php?

Сейчас там:

$u_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$u_phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$u_mail = $_POST['user_mail'];
$u_cours = $_POST['user_cours_lite'];

Comment: для начала, если отправляете по мейлу, то нужно понимать, что вам могут прислать веселый код, почитайте про экранирование и безопасность и только потом делайте подобное. что касается ответа на сам вопрос: $_POST['course_type'] будет активным, можно использовать как угодно. У вас там есть <input type="hidden" name="user_cours_lite" value="Модуль Lite">, но это тупо для каждого из модулей использовать отдельную переменную.

Comment: не за что, обращайтесь. я учился программировать как раз из-за того что купил скрипт с кучей уязвимостей...это было 10 лет назад =)